# No results when searching space separated string using RestHighLevelClient (JAVA Spring-boot)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using RestHighLevelClient for consuming elastic API's.

RestHighLevelClient version: 6.4.3
Elastic version: 6.7

I am getting correct results when passing a single string, but no results when passing space-separated strings, using RestHighLevelClient.
However the same works fine on Postman.

My JAVA code:

```
search(broker, "merchant_stores", QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("search_string", searchString).fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO), DeviceMerchantStore.class)
```

```
protected Flux<T> search(final String index, final String type, final QueryBuilder queryBuilder, final Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
        searchRequest.types(type);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        final SearchResponse searchResponse = elasticClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        final List<T> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for(SearchHit searchHit: searchResponse.getHits().getHits()) {
            l.add(new ObjectMapper().readValue(searchHit.getSourceAsString(), clazz));
        } return Flux.fromIterable(l);
    }
```

Query built on JAVA:

```
{
  "fuzzy" : {
    "search_string" : {
      "value" : "croma Maharashtra",
      "fuzziness" : "2",
      "prefix_length" : 0,
      "max_expansions" : 50,
      "transpositions" : false,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Query fired on Postman

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "search_string": {
        "query": "croma Maharashtra",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "boost":1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the same result because of the "transpositions" : false. Indeed, with a match (let s say you have std analyzer) it s like the transpositions is true (and you cant set him to false). So in the match query result ab = ba would be returned as in your fuzzy query they wont.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are not the same:

Change:

```
QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("search_string", searchString).fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO)
```

To:

```
QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("search_string", searchString).fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO).transpositions(false)
```